# How to sort a column (with additional columns) to match another column in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010, vlookup

How do I sort multiple records (rows) in Excel to match a specified order by providing a column that it should match?

So lets say for example I have records in a worksheet as below:

```
Name    Age    Sex    
Tom     20      M
Andrew  30      M
Mike    33      M
```

And I want to sort the records looking at the first column (Name). **Not alphabetically** but by any order I prefer. For example I want to sort it so that the first column matches this order so I provide a separate column as:

```
Andrew
Mike
Tom
```

So in this case I want the entire record set (name, age, sex) to be moved around to match this order. So final should output should look like:

```
Name    Age    Sex
Andrew  30      M
Mike    33      M    
Tom     20      M
```

Trying to do this in Excel 2010, so I'll have both the table data and match column in the same worksheet. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your data sample, the desired sort order is alphabetical by first name, for which you can just use the built-in sort functionality.

If you want a custom sort order, create a custom list, as pointed out by pnuts in the comment. Click File > Options > Advanced > find the button Edit Custom Lists and create a custom list.

Alternatively, create a helper table. Put the names in the first column, in the desired order. In the next column number the cells from 1 to the end, so now the  sort order number is in that column. Add a lookup column to your data table and perform a `=vlookup(name,HelperTable,2,0)`, copy down, then sort the table by that helper column.